# Can't split my kivy programm into different files

Tags: python, kivy

I wanted to make an kivy game with an enemy class.
In order to make it more easy to understand, I want to make an own file for my `Enemy` class, called `enemy.py`.
But I get the error:  `kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <Level>`

Here is the code of my main file:

```
from enemy import *

class Level(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Level, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.l_Clock = Clock
        self.l_Clock.schedule_interval(self.Update, 2/1.)
    def Update(self, *args):
        self.add_widget(Enemy(pos=(800, 300)))

root = Builder.load_file('main.kv')

class app(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        return root

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app().run()
```

Here is my main.kv file:

```
FloatLayout:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
    Level:
        id: level
```

And here is my enemy.py file:

```
root = Builder.load_file('main.kv')


class Sprite(Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Sprite, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size = self.texture_size

class Enemy(Widget):
    droga = StringProperty('feind.png')
    velocity = ListProperty([1, 0])
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Enemy, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.Update, 1/60.)
        self.skin = Sprite(source=self.droga)
        self.add_widget(self.skin)
    def Update(self, *args):
        self.x -= self.velocity[0]
        if self.x < 1:
            self.velocity[0] = 0
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        obj = root.ids.level
        obj.remove_widget(self)
```

Why can't my program find the Enemy Widget?

Comment: Is this your real code? In my opinion you should get an error because of a circular `import`.

Comment: @Matthias I left the import options out, because it would be to big then

Comment: You have a circular import.  You import enemy from main and main from enemy.  You need to change it so it's only one direction